# what is the purpose of adding "struct name *next" inside "struct name" in linked list. I mean i actually cant process what exactly happens

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct employ
{
    int reg;
    int sal;
    char *name;
    struct employ *next; // I want to know the purpose of this line
}EMP;

int main(void)
{
    EMP *first,*emp1,*emp2,*emp3,*ans;
    first = (EMP *)malloc(sizeof(EMP));
    first->next = NULL;
    /////first///////
    emp1 = (EMP *)malloc(sizeof(EMP));
    if(emp1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc error");
        exit(1);
    }

    emp1->reg = 100;
    emp1->sal = 30000;
    emp1->name = "james";
    emp1->next = first;
    first = emp1;

    /* I havent completed the program bcoz its not necessary here */
```

Comment: http://careerride.com/C-self-referential-structure.aspx

Comment: I hope you understand what a linked list is(If you did understand linked list than,probably you wouldn't be asking this question).

Comment: Looking through Wikipedia article on [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In a linked list, each node contains a pointer to the next node.

```
struct employ *next;
```

is used to achieve that effect

```
+---------+        +---------+
|  Node1  |------->|  Node2  |----> ...  
+---------+        +---------+
```

if you are in node1, next is a pointer to node2, that way you can accesss next element from the current element

Comment: Contains a pointer to the next node or `NULL` for the last node

Answer (score 2):

A linked list is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Here the `reg`, `sal` and `*name` represent your data structure and `*next` will hold the link to next element in the list.

Consider the following data structure

```
struct sample {
 int number;
 struct sample *next;
};
```

The pictorial representation for this structure would be

[image]

The above example has 3 elements, every element is an individual structure variable. In the above example the variable 1 has members `number` and `*next`. Here, the `number` contains `12` and the `*next` contains the address of the structure variable holding the data `99`. Since the type of the variable holding the data `99` is of type `struct sample` that is why we take `*next` type as `struct sample` type.

Comment: all i needed was the line "Since the type of the variable holding the data 99 is of type struct sample that is why we take *next type as struct sample type":) . TY